# python eve - return a response on pre-request

Tags: python, eve

I am developing a rest-api using python-eve.  My object contains a url, a description and an image.  Users can either insert or view a product (for inserting - the user simply adds a url, and the description and image are generated).

In order to avoid repetitive updates - when a user inserts a url which already exists using a POST request, I would like to redirect him to the url of the item corresponding to that url.  In order to do that, I added this code:

```
def pre_post_callback(request, lookup):
    prev_object = current_app.data.driver.db['products'].find_one({"url":lookup.values['url']})
    if prev_object:
      # here I would like to redirect the user to the /product/id of the product corresponding.

app.on_pre_POST += pre_post_callback
```

However, when adding the same url twice, I keep adding(overriding) the existing item.

How do I redirect the user to the already-existing product from the pre-post callback hook?

Comment: are you sure that `lookup` is working here? the docs say this: `Callbacks will receive the resource being requested, the original flask.request object and the current lookup dictionary as arguments (only exception being the on_pre_POST hook which does not provide a lookup argument).`

Comment: and what's the code in your `if prev_object` block

Comment: The code in the if condition was generally a redirect,however it did not work.my question is how do i return a response in this stage(in that if condition)?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you well, you want to respond to a POST (write) request with a lookup-like response. In REST you really don't want to do that, and Eve (being a REST framework) isn't really suited for that, although you could probably achieve a similar result with some hacking.

What you would probably do in your case is set `unique` rule for the `url` field, so the POST would eventually get a `409 Conflict` response.

Comment: i am not sure,as when the url of the item inserted does not exist - i would like to continue and create it,And if it does not - i'd like to return GET response for the object that does exist with that url

Comment: If it does not exist the POST will create it. You will get a 429 only when/if the url exists already.

Comment: I understand that.i appllied the hook in order to check if it already exists,and if it does - return the old object that already exist.how do i do that instead of getting 429